# VBA macro for if Excel Cell Contains Text Then Copy specific set of cells (not entire row) to Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where I am trying to copy a set of cells from one worksheet to another sheet in the same spreadsheet if it has certain text in the a certain range of cells ("YES").

I am VERY new to VBA, so pardon if this is horrible lol. Currently, when I run the macro, a value does pop up in Sheet 6, but only one return. It returns *exactly* what I need but it's just one return compared to the other 50 I know should be showing up.

Here is what I have tried:

```
Dim StatusCol As Range
Dim Status As Range
Dim PasteCell As Range

Set StatusCol = Sheet1.Range("F3:F101")

For Each Status In StatusCol

    If Sheet5.Range("A2") = "" Then
        Set PasteCell = Sheet6.Range("A2")
    Else
        Set PasteCell = Sheet6.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    If Status = "YES" Then Range(Status.End(xlToLeft), Status.End(xlToRight)).Copy PasteCell
    
Next Status
'
Set StatusCol = Sheet1.Range("O3:O46")

For Each Status In StatusCol

    If Sheet5.Range("A2") = "" Then
        Set PasteCell = Sheet6.Range("A2")
    Else
        Set PasteCell = Sheet6.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If

    If Status = "YES" Then Range(Status.End(xlToLeft), Status.End(xlToRight)).Copy PasteCell
    
Next Status
```

(I then want to repeat this for other sections of Sheet5 so I was planning on repeating this macro).

Comment: Have you noticed that you are checking if cell A2 of Sheet5 is empty, but afterwards you copy the data into Sheet6?

Comment: try using `Set PasteCell = Sheet6.Cells(Sheet6.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)` also if `Sheet5.Range("A2") = ""` you will always be pasting to `Sheet6.Range("A2")`